# Convert underscore in ES6 Methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, redux, underscore.js

I have an existing codebase that uses AngularJS, Redux and Underscore. In that codebase I have the following code:

```
const selectedBroker = _.findWhere(state.brokers, { brokerId: action.payload });
  return state.merge({
    selectedBroker,
    selectedBrokerId: action.payload,
  });
```

**I want to convert it to an es6 Method. I think the `find()`, would be suitable, but don't know how.** Could you help me a little bit? Thanks!!

Also it is not in the scope of this task but I see more underscore methods here. Like `_.reject, _.contains, _.map`. Could you also convert that in the context similar to the above code example.

Comment: You could use `babel-core` to generate an AST, transform the nodes pointing to `_.method` calls and compile the AST back to code. To use `find` in place of findWhere, the following might do `selectedBroker = state.brokers.find(({brokerId}) => brokerId === action.payload)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be just like below, **[array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** will return the first matching element in the array.

```
let selectedBroker = state.brokers.find(broker => broker.brokerId == action.payload);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a question. In this case, you used `t=>t.brokerId`. Could you explain the logic? That part of the code always frustrates and confuse me. I mean what is the `t`?

Comment: @DimitrisEfstathiadis This might make more sense: `state.brokers.find(broker=>broker.brokerId == action.payload);` It's just the variable name assigned to the entry each loop.

Comment: t is the object where t.brokertId is the value that brokerId holds which will be compared with action.payload if it matches find will return the matching element

Comment: Thank you both guys. That helped a lot..

Comment: @DimitrisEfstathiadis mark if the answer helped